# scraping links from web page chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to extract all hyperlinks from a webpage using a Google Chrome extension. This is easy but I can't spend anymore time trying to understand what stupid thing I have done wrong. Here my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "RL Helper",
  "description": "This extension examines the Ralph Lauren website.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["RLHelperBackground.js"]
    },
    "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "RL3.jpg"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "https://www.ralphlauren.com/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

This runs real nice but when I click on the icon, nothing happens. Here is the background.js:

```
console.log ('RLHELPER BACKGROUND.JS v 1.0');

////////////// LISTENERS //////////////////  

//  ON CLICKED PAGE ACTION
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(doIconClick);   

//  ON UPDATED TABS
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(doTabUpdatedAction);

// ON REMOVED TABS
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(doTabRemovedAction);

// ON EXTENSION REQUEST
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(doOnRequestAction);

function doIconClick(tab) // examine current page when icon clicked
{
    console.log('Icon Clicked in Window '+tab.windowId+' Tab '+tab.id+' on '+tab.url.split('?')[0]);
    mainWindowId=tab.windowId;
    timeOfFirstRequest=new Date().getTime();
    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://www.ralphlauren.com") > -1)
    {
        console.log('  Ralph Lauren Home page');
        searchProcessTabId=tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(searchProcessTabId, {file: "pageScraper.js"});
    };
}
function doTabUpdatedAction(tab_id, data, tab)
{
    console.log('Window '+tab.windowId+' Tab '+tab_id+' Updated '+tab.url.split('?')[0]+' Status: '+data.status);
    if (data.status=='complete')
    {//do these only on 'complete', not also on 'loading'
        if (tab.url.indexOf("https://www.ralphlauren.com") > -1)
        {
            console.log('Displaying Icon');
            chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
        }
    }   
}
console.log('RLHELPER BACKGROUND.JS waiting for events'); console.log(' ');
```

This code is adapted from a scraper I built four years ago that worked great. But a lot has changed. Now the console log shows all the console messages to EOF of Background.js but when I click on the icon, I get only that the icon has been displayed and clicked on but nothing more.  Can't tell if the script is getting injected or not. Here is the onClick js.

```
//pageScraper.js v 1
console.log('');
console.log('pageScraper.js version 1');

//display number of links in page
console.log(document.GetElementsByTagName("a").length);

console.log('pageScraper.js READY');
```

There's something dumb here that I'm missing. I should be able to do this in the background page, let alone send a script out to do this simple work.

Answer (score 1):

I was right. This was an incredibly stupid question. I simply forgot that each tab has its own console, so I was only looking at the background page console and expecting to see my messages. When I finally had the target page open for inspection with the background page console in the foreground, I noticed the response on the target page console.

Comment: any chance you could post the missing "pageScraper.js" file, thx